# Send variable value from server to client

Tags: java, swing

On the server I created a counter that calculates and displays time on the server (from 180 seconds to 0). The current number of seconds is stored in the variable `time` and displayed in `jLabel (name seconds)` on the server.

On the client side, there is also `JLabel (name seconds)` in which I would like to display the current second displayed on the server. Is there a way to send `jLabel (name seconds)` (server) to `jLabel (name seconds)` (client)?

```java
 try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        if(i<120 && i>=60){
            int time=i%60;
            String sekundy=Integer.toString(time);
            minutes.setText("01");
            seconds.setText(sekundy);
       }
    }

void uruchom() throws Exception
    {
        Socket socket = s.accept();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        while(true)
        {
            String przekazSekundy=seconds.getText();
            String przekazMinuty=minutes.getText();
            try
                {

                   //I try doing something like this

                    out.seconds.setText(przekazSekundy);
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("error");
                    socket.close();
                    return;
                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: There are many ways to communicate between a client and a server. The way that would suit your system best is highly dependent on many factors like your current architecture, preferences, ease of use etc.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

for the serverside:

```
PrintWriter writer;
writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream();
writer.println(przekazSekundy);
writer.flush();
```

on clientside :

```
in = socket.getInputStream();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String newstring = "";
message = "";
while(!(newstring = reader.readLine()).equals("")){
    message+=newstring;
    if(!reader.ready())
        break;
}
if(message != "")
   //set your client label text
```